# Apache Jira Export Search Results Excel, only 100 results exported

Tags: apache, jira, bug-tracking

If you log in to Apache Jira and using the advanced search option, put

```
issuetype = Bug AND status = Closed AND resolution = Fixed AND assignee !=unassigned AND (summary~ "\"large number\"" OR description~ "\"large number\"")
```

in there, you will see there are total of 174 bug reports. When I try to export them as excel file, only 100 results was saved in the bug report. Looks like there is some kind of limit. How can I download all the bug report to a EXCEL FILE????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be there is a limitation to export tickets..instead of click export just right click on the export link and copy link location and paste it in another tab then navigate to the end of the url and see there is a "tempMax=100" then edit this number as you prefer and then press enter. more information follow this [link](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Exporting+a+filter+result+containing+more+than+1000+issues)

Comment: seems you using older version of jira isn't it?..ok I guess then you have to edit the jira-application.properties file  in <jira-install>/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/ follow link I posted in the answer it include what you all need.Good luck..before you editing its good to have a backup of that property file..;)